# Remove Duplicates in two-dimensional array while maintaining sequence

Tags: python, arrays

I have found a lot of threads on removing duplicates in arrays but none for my specific use-case. I have a two-dimensional list that I need to remove duplicates from however I must maintain the original sequence

```
mylist = [['Installation', '64%'], ['C2', '14%'], ['NA', '14%'], ['C2', '14%'], ['NA', '14%'], ['na', '7%']]
```

I need to simply drop the duplicates without re-arranging, so..

```
newlist = [['Installation', '64%'], ['C2', '14%'], ['NA', '14%'], ['na', '7%']]
```

appreciate any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) to keep track of seen items:

```
>>> mylist = [['Installation', '64%'], ['C2', '14%'], ['NA', '14%'], ['C2', '14%'], ['NA', '14%'], ['na', '7%']]
>>> seen = set()
>>> newlist = []
>>> for item in mylist:
...     t = tuple(item)
...     if t not in seen:
...         newlist.append(item)
...         seen.add(t)
...
>>> newlist
[['Installation', '64%'], ['C2', '14%'], ['NA', '14%'], ['na', '7%']]
```

**NOTE**

You need to convert a list to tuple (list is not hashable); can't add a list to set.

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> seen.add([1,2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> seen.add(tuple([1,2]))
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
mylist = [['Installation', '64%'], ['C2', '14%'], ['NA', '14%'], ['C2', '14%'], ['NA', '14%'], ['na', '7%']]
result = []
for x in mylist:
    if x not in result:
        result.append(x)
print result
```

`[['Installation', '64%'], ['C2', '14%'], ['NA', '14%'], ['na', '7%']]`

Comment: Loved this. Is there a way to remove the item from the list, if the list is mutable? Instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 2):

import `numpy` as `np` :

```
myList = [['Installation', '64%'], ['C2', '14%'], ['NA', '14%'], ['C2', '14%'], ['NA', '14%'], ['na', '7%']]

mylist=np.unique(myList,axis=0)

print (mylist)
```