# Remove duplicates values across the multi-dimensional array in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to remove duplicates across the multi-dimensional array:
example:

```
[
[125.25,129,128,129],
[124.25,127,130,131],
[126,126,125,124],
[126,124,130,124]
]
```

and I want, the output should be:

```
[
[125.25,129,128],
[124.25,127,130,131],
[126,125,124]
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Duplicates in two-dimensional array while maintaining sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065347/remove-duplicates-in-two-dimensional-array-while-maintaining-sequence)

Comment: No, I need each element of all arrays should be unique, no duplication of values across the array.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem individually. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you finished before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the shortest but something like this would work:

```
arrs = [
[125.25,129,128,129],
[124.25,127,130,131],
[126,126,125,124],
[126,124,130,124]
]

alreadyExisting = []
removedDuplicatesArr = []

for arr in arrs:
    newArr = []
    for i in arr:
        if i not in alreadyExisting:
            alreadyExisting.append(i)
            newArr.append(i)
    if newArr:
        removedDuplicatesArr.append(newArr)

print(removedDuplicatesArr)
```

Comment: I'd make `alreadyExisting` a `set` to make the `if i not in alreadyExisting` check O(1).

Answer (score 0):

```
yourlist = [
    [125.25,129,128,129],
    [124.25,127,130,131],
    [126,126,125,124],
    [126,124,130,124]
]
def seen(element, _cache=set()):
    result = element in _cache
    _cache.add(element)
    return result

filtered = ([x for x in sublist if not seen(x)] for sublist in yourlist)
filtered = [sublist for sublist in filtered if sublist] # filter out empty lists
```

Comment: Almost - what about empty lists? In his example, these are removed

Answer (score 0):

Use `set` to eliminate the duplicates in sublists , then check if item of sublist exists in `res` if not append those values to a `tmp` list and then append that list to your `res`

```
res = []
lst = [set(i) for i in lst]

for i in lst:
    tmp = []
    for j in i:
        if not any(j in i for i in res):
            tmp.append(j)
    if tmp:
        res.append(sorted(tmp))

print(res)
# [[125.25, 128, 129], [124.25, 127, 130, 131], [124, 125, 126]]
```