# compare each items of a list with the rest and remove matched elements from the list while iterating

Tags: python-3.x, list

My input data is

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [1, 2, 7], [8, 2], [9, 5]]
```

My expected output is:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2, 7], [8, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [9, 5]]
```

With the help of [How to compare each item in a list with the rest, only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16603357/1772898) currently my snippet looks like

```
mylist = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [1, 2, 7], [8, 2], [9, 5]]
result = list()

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    result.append(mylist[i])
    for j in range(i + 1, len(mylist)):
        if set(mylist[i]) & set(mylist[j]):
            result.append(mylist[j])
            mylist.remove(mylist[j])

print(result)
```

However, It is throwing error `IndexError: list index out of range`. I guess this is because I am trying to remove items from a list while iterating.

So I checked [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207461/1772898). It suggested using slice or itertools. It also gave a code snippet which I found much more readable.

```
temp = []
while somelist:
    x = somelist.pop()
    if not determine(x):
        temp.append(x)
while temp:
    somelist.append(templist.pop())
```

However, I could not figure out how it might work. Any idea?

**Update 1**

Snippet:

```
mylist = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [1, 2, 7], [8, 2], [9, 5]]
result = list()

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    result.append(mylist[i])
    for j in range(i + 1, len(mylist)):
        if set(mylist[i]) & set(mylist[j]):
            result.append(mylist[j])
            # mylist.remove(mylist[j])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2, 7], [8, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [9, 5], [1, 2, 7], [8, 2], [8, 2], [9, 5]]
```

I do not want `[1, 2, 7], [8, 2], [8, 2], [9, 5]` in the result so I trying to use `mylist.remove(mylist[j])`, which I could not figure out how to do.

Comment: How can u use this list for testing? There aren't any repeated values in this list.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065347/remove-duplicates-in-two-dimensional-array-while-maintaining-sequence) answer your question?

Comment: I don't get the logic by which you rearrange your list.

Comment: @venky__ let me check it out.

Comment: @Sushil I am comparing them as set using `set(mylist[i]) & set(mylist[j])`

Comment: @PatrickArtner the logic is - take the first element and append in the result list. Then compare `set(mylist[i]) & set(mylist[j])` and if match append in the result list, and also remove the element from `mylist[j]`.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Please let me rephrase. I am trying to compare each element of the list with rest of the elements. If match found, I am trying to add it to the result list and then remove the matched elements from the list.

Comment: @venky__ No, it does not answer my question.

Comment: I have updated the question to make it a little more clear.

Comment: If u don't want ```[1, 2, 7], [8, 2], [8, 2], [9, 5]``` in the ```result```, then y r u removing it from ```mylist```?

Comment: @Sushil Given `mylist` is the input, If I do not remove the data which I do not want to duplicate from `mylist` it gives duplicate results in output which is `result`

Comment: @Sushil please let me rephrase. In my case, there is data in input which I am iterating over and over. If I do not remove the data from the input when I am moving it to the result, then it gets duplicated.

Comment: @blueray Check if my answer satisfies ur requirement.

Comment: @blueray Thx for accepting my answer as the best answer. Could u also upvote my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...So from ur ques, I understand that u wanna remove the repeated values from `result`. I tried to complete this task using `list.remove`, but I couldn't. So I have done it in a different way. Instead of using `list.remove`, add these lines to ur code:

```
import copy
curr_lst = []

resultdup = copy.deepcopy(result)

for x in range(len(resultdup)):
    curr_lst = resultdup[x]
    for y in range(x+1,len(resultdup)):
        if curr_lst == resultdup[y]:
            indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(result) if x == curr_lst]
            for x in indices[1:]:
                del result[x]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2, 7], [8, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [9, 5]]
```

Hope that this helps u.

Comment: Just add it at the end.

Comment: Last night I found an alternative solution. I added it as well in case someone need it.

Answer (score 1):

OP Here, I could not find the answer of the question I originally asked. However, I found an alternative way (though it might not be as optimal as removing the element from `mylist[j]`) to achieve the result I was expecting.

The code I am currently using is:

```
mylist = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [1, 2, 7], [8, 2], [9, 5]]
temp_result = list()

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    temp_result.append(mylist[i])
    for j in range(i + 1, len(mylist)):
        if (set(mylist[i]) & set(mylist[j])):
            temp_result.append(mylist[j])

result = []
for elem in temp_result:
    if elem not in result:
        result.append(elem)

print(result)
```